# How to get the last 3 rows from MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I wanted to get only the last 3 rows of my database here is the query that I tried

```
select top 3 * from poem where MemberID = 54;
```

But there was an error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '3 * from poem where MemberID = 54' at line 1
```

This is an example of one of the data stored in my table poem

```
MariaDB [bigproject]> select PoemID, Title, Description from poem where MemberID = 79;
+--------+------------------------+--------------------+
| PoemID | Title                  | Description        |
+--------+------------------------+--------------------+
|     34 | Everything Has Changed | EHC                |
|     52 | Kapono                 | Poetic             |
|     53 | Love under the sky     | How is your heart? |
|     54 | Imaginary              | Imagine me         |
+--------+------------------------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

I only wanted to get the last 3 rows of this.

Thank you!!

Comment: select  * from poem where MemberID = 54 LIMIT 3   May be this is acceptable for My SQL

Comment: top n syntax is for SQL server, in your case, you should use the limit keyword: 
select * from poem where MemberID = 54 LIMIT 3.
On the other hand, there is no such thing as last 3 rows, you must select you rows based on a specified order, for example a date, an ID, etc... For instance, if you order by poemID descending, you will get the last 3 poems for MemberID 54, on the other hand if your order by ascending you will get the first three.

Comment: On a side note: You are confusing the term "database" with the term table "table". You want to select data from a table in a database.

Comment: @ElieAsmar it works thanks! Its a big help